# Find the weather of Australian city using zip code in kksou Google Weather Module in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am using the module kksou Google Weather Module. It displays the weather of a  particular city (for US and UK only using zip code and displays the weather of city). If i want to display the Weather for the cities in Australia using zip code only don't want to type the city name.What i have to do?.
[Please check the demo](http://www.kksou.com/t1510/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=59)

Answer (score 0):

I just installed and tried it without a problem with these steps for a city:
From administrator, edit the module and set *Default City* to **Sydney**, and set *Hide Input Field* to **yes**.

It only supports the ZipCodes you mentioned, so you'll need to map them somehow on your own if you want to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.My need is i have to give the postcode of any cities of the Australia to the text field.It should display the weather of a particular city based on the postcode. Currently it shows the  weather of cities in US and UK by using zipcode.